# How do you remove the sprocket from an eighthinch splined BMX style crankset?

Tags: crankset, chainring, bmx

I have the [EighthInch Freestyle Splined Crankset](http://www.eighthinch.com/14-eighthinch-splined-crankset.aspx). These are very similar to profile bmx cranksets.

I purchased a larger sprocket to use with the crankset. I've used a crank puller to remove the drive side crankarm, but couldn't figure out how to remove the sprocket. It won't just slide off the axle. It fits on the crankset with very small splines. What should I do to remove the sprocket (aka chainring)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap tap tap tap tap.

And then tap tap some more.

If this is what I am thinking of you either tap the inside of the chainring from the non drive side. Or you tap the spindle from the drive side which should push the spindle through the chainring and bottom bracket. Or a little of both.

Tap tap with a wood block.

Greasing before install goes a long way to make these things easy. They are made to be tight!

You could improvise a automotive gear puller but the hammer should work.

Comment: The sprocket came off with some hammering, but the eighthinch sprocket also had a small splined carrier which is still stuck on the axle. It seems much harder to remove. Do I have to pull the axle out and try and hammer this off as well (likely with a piece of pipe just larger than the axle)?

Comment: Old sprocket came with the steel insert, new one does not need the steel insert.

Comment: @Benzo yeah I'd remove the spindle and use a piece of pipe. If you don't have the pipe you can probably lightly tap as you move around. As I mentioned you can also use a gear puller.